# How to find out when the script was executed last time in PHP?

Tags: php

I want to create a PHP script, which would be launched regularily as a cron job.
But sometimes I may launch it manually.
The script must modify MySQL rows created from the time of its last execution and I want to avoid modifying the same row twice.
Each row contains its creation time.
I don't want to clutter my database with a whole column to hold last modification time for each row.

To narrow the problem down, I need a variable `$last_execution_time` to hold a timestamp, written on the last script execution.

What is the correct and elegant way to do this?

Comment: How can you maintain a variable in cron without any reference you need to interact with database for your problems solution

Comment: I've  updated the question. 
The script must know the time when it was executed last time, that's all I need.

Comment: write time to file. if you lock it, while srcipt running, you avoid simultaneous calls problem

Comment: @splash58, that's exactly what I was going to do. Why didn't you post this as an answer?

Comment: @HelgaIliashenko I've done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write time to file.

When script is running, lock the file, to avoid the  simultaneous calls problem

Answer (score 0):

Pull out the last known record from the DB.

Select lastupdatetime from table limit 1 order by id desc

Make a check to see if it's before current time stamp etc

So use the data in the database to help yo